# Is there a Map with a variable key length in Java world?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I need a Map but when I call get(key, n) it should should return not only all the records with the searched key value, but also all where the n last significant bits of the key are the same as the search key (e.g. applying something like key&(1<<(n+1)-1)).

Is there something like this already implemented in Java?

Comment: Why not just make the actual key just the n least significant bits of the computed key?

Comment: @GregS: I believe the OP wants `n` to be given on the fly, per query.

Comment: Clearly something as specific as this isn't available in the standard library. The question is: can't you just use the n last significant bits as the key and a list as the value? Why specify a key that you can't actually use?

Comment: Given how unusual these requriements are it's extremely unlikely such a thing is already available

Comment: @GregS - The getter can specify any value of n from 1 to N, so you'd have to store N-1 entries for each key of N bits if you did it that way.

Comment: You could possibly iterate through a treemap? There is a solution which I think is similar to what you're asking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537921/efficiently-iterate-through-all-matching-keys-in-a-hashmap - specifically see http://stackoverflow.com/a/537957/201648

Comment: My first port of call is always http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/ but unfortunately there's nothing like this there. The closest would be the MultiKeyMap but this is presumably not what you want (if you want run-time derived number of bits for the key).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not quite, but you can use a [NavigableMap.subMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) to implement this. e.g.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Value> map =
int keyBase = key & ~((1 << n)-1);
Map<Integer, Value> subMap = map.subMap(keyBase, true, keyBase + (1 << n), false);
```

If you want to search based on the lowest bits instead of the highest bits, you have to reverse the bits before adding and searching.  This will group together the lowest bit, second lowest bit then third lowest bit etc.

Comment: I think you need to reverse the bits of the key, because the OP wants to keep the least significant, not the most significant bits.

Comment: Yes, @dasblinkenlight.  It looks like the code above accepts the keys with the same  `(64 - (n - 1))` *leftmost* bits instead of the `n` *rightmost* bits.

Comment: Have added a comment on how to sort by lowest bit first.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is not going to do it, but a TreeMap could.

You will need to normalize and reverse your keys (i.e. decide how many bits you'd like to keep, and reverse the bits to make the less significant bits to be your most significant). Then you can strip the less significant bits (formerly the most significant bits) from your keys, and use range searches of the tree map to find your answer.